# How to send non-local mail, with GMail(GApps) SMTP?

Tags: debian, email, sendmail, smtp

I have some (~3) Debian boxes, and I want to post system mail to my non-local mailbox. But I have a problem with configuring `exim4`. Also I don't like so much exim4's config. Too different, and also with my last try I had to store the password unencrypted.

I have 2 questions:

1. How do I configure outgoing mail with GMail/GApps SMTP?  (password stored encypted)
2. How to return **all** of **MY** and **ROOT**'s mails to my other address, sent trough the *new SMTP*?

Any question, or info needed, just comment. I would really appreciate any tutorial!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need to use exim4?

I recommend using postfix. This guide helps you do this **with encrypted password**
http://www.marksanborn.net/linux/send-mail-postfix-through-gmails-smtp-on-a-ubuntu-lts-server/

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll try it out. (Otherwise, it seems to be a little out-of-date. I don't think, I have to gen 3 certs. ProFTPd, Apache doesn't need so much to use TLS. But, I'll try.)